# How to make a plot visualizing timing of animal retraps in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have a large database of tagged animals (starting from 2011 to 2014). My aim is to visualize the data in a way that **each tagged individual will have its own line starting at the time of tagging**, i.e. first caught and ending at the time when individual was last caught. These two events (as well as retraps between will be marked by full circle. **Additional information (empty circle) should be given in timing of events, when individual was not caught, be I know that it was alive in that time** (probably the picture below will better explain).

Is there any R package (function) capable of creating such plot? For example some package directly used for animal trapping data?

I tried to draw the plot according to `my.data`

[image]

```
my.data <- data.frame(individual = c("ind_01","ind_02","ind_01",
                                     "ind_02","ind_02","ind_03",
                                     "ind_04","ind_04","ind_03",
                                     "ind_05","ind_06","ind_03",
                                     "ind_05","ind_02","ind_06"),
                      day = rep(1, times = 15),
                      month = c(2,2,9,9,4,4,4,11,3,3,3,8,8,12,12),
                      year = c(rep(c(2011,2012,2013),
                               times = c(4,4,7))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ggplot` to do this, I transformed the data a bit, basically casted the data to  add all possible trap dates to all individuals.

If the individual was not trapped this add an NA in the casted data frame if the animal was not sighted. I then changed all NAs that are between sightings to `not_seen`, melted the data to plot it and added a column with the year of first sighting.

```
library(reshape2)
#make a date column with the day, month and year
my.data$date <- as.Date(paste(my.data$day,my.data$month,my.data$year,sep="-"),format="%d-%m-%Y")

#cast the data to have individuals as columns and dates as row
cast_data<-dcast(my.data,date~individual,value.var="individual")
rownames(cast_data)<-cast_data$date
cast_data <- cast_data[,-1]

#replace the NAs that are between animal sightings with "not_seen"
obs_data <- apply(cast_data,2,function(x){
  seen_dates <- which(!is.na(x))
  x[seen_dates] <- "seen"
  x[setdiff(seq(seen_dates[1],tail(seen_dates,1)),seen_dates)]<-"not_seen"
  x
})

#melt the data and add a first_seen column that has the year of first sighting
data<-as.data.frame(melt(obs_data))
head(data)
colnames(data) <- c("obs_date","ind_id","obs")

data<-data[!is.na(data$obs),]
data$obs_date<-as.Date(data$obs_date)
for (i in unique(data$ind_id)){
  data[data$ind_id==i,4] <- format(data[data$ind_id==i,1][1],"%Y")
}
colnames(data) <- c("obs_date","ind_id","obs","first_seen")

#use ggplot to make the plot
ggplot(data,aes(obs_date,ind_id,colour=first_seen))+geom_point(aes(shape=obs),size=10)+scale_x_date()+geom_line()+scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,19))
```

[image]